# Permission error in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to access a directory that I had for the logs in tensorflow however I get the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tensorflow'
```

when I run this line

```
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tensorflow/logdir', sess.graph_def)
```

Comment: show the owner of `/tensorflow/logdir`, maybe the program didn't have the access right to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permission settings. You likely do not have local write privileges to that directory.

In *Nix systems, do

```
ls -l / | grep tensorflow
```

However, as it looks like you installed that in the root folder (`/`), I am almost certain this is the case. To transfer the ownership to you, as a user, do:

```
sudo chown $user -R /tensorflow
sudo chmod -r 775 /tensorflow   # root/user get rwx, other gets rx
```

Where `$user` is your user name. You can omit the first command if you just want to be able to write to the folder, and not transfer the ownership to you, the current user. If you omit the first step, however, make sure to change `775` to `777`, so all users get read/write/execute privileges.

If you do not have superuser privileges, ask whoever does to give you write permissions to `/tensorflow`, or a local save directory to do so.

In the future, try writing to locations where you have local permissions.
For more information on Unix file permissions, see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm):

> The permissions are broken into groups of threes, and each position in the group denotes a specific permission, in this order: read (r), write (w), execute (x) −
>
> The first three characters (2-4) represent the permissions for the file's owner. For example -rwxr-xr-- represents that onwer has read (r), write (w) and execute (x) permission.
>
> The second group of three characters (5-7) consists of the permissions for the group to which the file belongs. For example -rwxr-xr-- represents that group has read (r) and execute (x) permission but no write permission.
>
> The last group of three characters (8-10) represents the permissions for everyone else. For example -rwxr-xr-- represents that other world has read (r) only permission.
>
> File Access Modes
>   The permissions of a file are the first line of defense in the security of a Unix system. The basic building blocks of Unix permissions are the read, write, and execute permissions, which are described below −
>
> 1. Read
>      Grants the capability to read ie. view the contents of the file.
> 2. Write
>      Grants the capability to modify, or remove the content of the file.
> 3. Execute
>      User with execute permissions can run a file as a program.

Comment: When I type the directory starting with / where does the path start?

Comment: @ShawnImm, that's root on Unix systems. Normally, only superusers have root access. Individual users only have access to files under a subdirectory in `/home`, or for Mac OS X, `/Users`.